# How to set the parent of QObject as a parent that is in a seperate thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt6

```
class DownloadWindow(QWidget):
     # Irrelevant class attributes and methods

    self.downloads_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    

    @pyqtSlot(str, int, dict)   
    def receive_download_progress_bar_details(self, episode_title: str, episode_size: int):
        bar = DownloadProgressBar(None, "Downloading", episode_title, 400, 33, episode_size, "MB", ibytes_to_mbs_divisor)
        self.downloads_layout.insertWidget(0, bar)

class DownloadManagerThread(QThread):
    # Irrelevant class attributes and methods 

    send_progress_bar_details = pyqtSignal(str, int)
    # In __init__
     self.send_progress_bar_details.connect(download_window.receive_download_progress_bar_details)


    def run(self):
        for idx, link in enumerate(self.anime_details.direct_download_links):
            # Get progress bar data 

            self.send_progress_bar_details.emit(episode_title, download_size)
```

Error: `QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.`

The `DownloadWindow` object creates and calls `start()` on a `DownloadManagerThread` object, the `DownloadManagerThread` then eventually emits a signal containing the data necessary to create a `DownloadProgressBar` object.

My assumption was that since its a signal-slot connection the object will be created in the `DownloadWindow`'s thread but apparently that's not the case, hence the error.

I've tried calling `QMetaObject.invokeMethod(bar, "setParent", Qt.ConnectionType.BlockedQueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QVBoxLayout, self.downloads_layout))` but I get a different error `QMetaMethod::invoke: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QVBoxLayout*'RuntimeError: QMetaObject.invokeMethod() call failed`. `DownloadProgressBar` is derived from`QWidget`.

I've tried calling `bar.moveToThread(self.thread())` but I still get the first error.

Basically what is the right way of setting a `QObject`s parent as a parent that is in a separate thread?

Comment: The connection to the signal (connect) should be made in the window and not in the thread class. A queued connection should also be used. Also you create a new download progress bar object for each progress update.

Comment: @MarcoF. I've tried your fix but I still get the first error. The for loop is for creating the  progress bars, for each iteration a ```DownloadProgressBar``` is created.

Comment: show your updated code plz..

Comment: ```def start_download(self, anime_details: AnimeDetails):
        self.current_download = DownloadManagerThread(self, anime_details, anime_progress_bar, downloaded_episode_count)
self.current_download.send_progress_bar_details.connect(self.receive_progress_bar_details, Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)

        self.current_download.start()```

@MarcoF. Above is the function in ```DownloadWindow``` that creates the ```DownloadManagerThread``` object and makes the connection you suggested

Comment: please update in the question. and please create a complete minimal example. i don't want to guess around..

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that it's probably just a bug, cause even when I try ```print(bar.thread() is self.thread())```   I get ```True``` meaning the ```DownloadProgressBar``` is in the same thread as ```DownloadWindow```, also nothing crashes even though the error is logged

Comment: i don't believe in a bug. without the complete code i can't help you. sry

Comment: @uZuMaKioBaRuTo You're just guessing and you're also forcing us to do so. Please edit the question with a **valid** [mre].

Comment: @musicamante I did, well sort of, but I didn't get the error, meaning there's probably something else on my end causing it, so I saw no point in editing the question with the example if it doesn't reproduce the error. What doesn't make sense is python says they're are on the same thread but PyQt is still logging the error.

Comment: `obj.thread()` doesn't return the actual thread in which the function is executed, so that check is irrelevant.

Comment: Post a [mre] with debugging details including a stack trace.